# Scan object is underfined in cordova-plugin-document-scanner

Tags: cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am trying to cordova-plugin-document-scanner in my ionic application. but in my device ready function, I cannot access the global scan object. Here is the code

```
this.platform.ready().then((readySource) => {
  console.log('Platform ready from', readySource);
  // Platform now ready, execute any required native code
 console.log(scan);      
});
```

and here is the exception

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: 'scan' is not defined
ReferenceError: 'scan' is not defined
at Anonymous function (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:839:13)
at t.prototype.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14879)
at onInvoke (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5134:17)
at t.prototype.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14879)
at r.prototype.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10117)
at Anonymous function (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20233)
at t.prototype.invokeTask
```

Can anybody help me where I am going wrong?

Comment: You are running this in a device? If so are you using livereload or something?

Comment: i am running it on my phone using ionic devapp. and ya i am using live reload.

Comment: I have found cordova plugins not working with livereload and devapp... You should try running the app directly in a device

Comment: i will try that. but when i try to import something from this plugin. then i get "module not found" error.. could this be a problem?

Comment: you get that at runtime?

Comment: i get this on compile time as well

Comment: Then its a different issue..

Comment: any help? :(. i am really struggling with this issue

Answer (score 2):

nice seeing you here :)

Just [linking](https://github.com/NeutrinosPlatform/cordova-plugin-document-scanner/issues/17) the solved github issue here, for future users.

Here are the steps :-

1) Create blank Ionic Project in terminal
    `ionic start myproject blank`

2) Add plugin to project
    `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-document-scanner`

3) Now navigate to `E:\myproject\src\app\app.component.ts`
    - add `declare var scan;` above `@Component({..` 
    - then inside `platform.ready().then(() => { }` function add
       the following function as shown in readme.

```
scan.scanDoc(1, onSuccess, onFail);

function onSuccess(imageURI) {
    //var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    //image.src = imageURI;
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

4) Then in terminal `ionic cordova run android`

5) Also don't forget to read the documentation and the other solutions to issues if you run into trouble.

Have a nice day all of you :)

Comment: Great solution, suggested solution worked well for me